# Conversion of Matlab sparse to Python scipy csr_matrix

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am new to both Matlab and Python and am converting some Matlab codes to it's Python equivalent. The issue I am facing is with converting from **sparse(i,j,v,m,n)** to **csr_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), [shape=(M, N)])**.

In this code, i, j and row_in, col_ind will be passed with an index array - **idx** of size(124416, 1), while v and data will be passed with a 2D array - **D22** of  size(290, 434)

**Matlab:**

```
...
H = 288;
W = 432;
N = (H+2)*(W+2);
mask = zeros(H+2, W+2);
mask(2:end-1, 2:end-1) = 1;

idx = find(mask==1);
>>>idx = [292, ..., 579, 582 ..., 869, ... , 125282, ..., 125569]

A = sparse(idx, idx+1, -D22(idx), N, N);
B = sparse(idx, idx-1, -D22(idx), N, N);
C = sparse(idx, idx+H+2, -D22(idx-1), N, N);
D = sparse(idx, idx-H-2, -D22(idx-1), N, N);
...
```

spy(A) first entry is **m(293, 292) - (idx,idx+1)**, which was what I expected.

spy(B) **m(292, 293) - (idx,idx-1).** 
I was expecting it to be m(291, 292), believing that idx-1 would return an array [291, ..., 578, 581 ..., 868, ... , 125281, ..., 125568]

spy(C) - **m(582, 292) - (idx,idx+H+2)**

spy(D) - **m(292, 582) - (idx,idx-H-2)**

Hence, given that was how I understood the indexing order, I translated the code into Python in this form

**Python:**

```
...
H = 288
W = 432
N = (H+2) * (W+2)
mask = np.zeros([H+2, W+2])
mask[1:-1,1:-1] = 1

idx = np.nonzero(mask.transpose() == 1)                                 
idx = np.vstack((idx[1], idx[0]))                                        
idx = np.ravel_multi_index(idx, ((H+2),(W+2)), order='F').copy()     # Linear Indexing as per Matlab
>>> idx
array([291, ..., 578, 581 ..., 868, ... , 125281, ..., 125568])

idx_ = np.unravel_index(idx, ((H+2),(W+2)), order='F')               # *** Back to Linear Indexing
idx_ = np.column_stack((idx_[0], idx_[1]))                           # *** combine tuple of 2 arrays
idx_H_2 = np.unravel_index(idx-H-2, ((H+2),(W+2)), order='F')
idx_H_2 = np.column_stack((idx_H_2[0], idx_H_2[1]))

A = sp.csr_matrix((-D22[idx_[:,0], idx_[:,1]], (idx+1,idx)), shape = (N,N))
B = sp.csr_matrix((-D22[idx_[:,0], idx_[:,1]], (idx-1,idx)), shape = (N,N))
C = sp.csr_matrix((-D11[idx_[:,0], idx_[:,1]], (idx+H+2,idx)), shape = (N,N)) 
D = sp.csr_matrix((-D11[idx_H_2[:,0], idx_H_2[:,1]], (idx-H-2,idx)), shape = (N,N)) 
...
```

For A, the first entry is **p(292, 291) - (idx+1,idx)**, and since Python starts from zero index, it refers to Matlab m(293, 292).

However for B, the first entry is **p(290, 291) - (idx-1,idx)**, which was what I had expected (the equivalent in Matlab should be m(291, 292) ), but as mentioned earlier the Matlab code returns (292, 293) instead.

C - **p(581, 291) - (idx+H+2,idx)**

D - **p(1, 291) - (idx-H-2,idx)**

Could anyone kindly explain what I might have understood incorrectly, and how should I revise my Python code to reflect the Matlab code more accurately.

---

Oh and just one more qns :)

**Matlab:**

```
A = A(idx,idx);
```

**Python:**

```
A = A[idx,:][:,idx]
```

Are the equivalent?

Thank you so much for your all kind help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines are confusing:

```
py(A) first entry is m(293, 292) - (idx,idx+1), which was what I expected.

spy(B) m(292, 293) - (idx,idx-1). I was expecting it to be m(291, 292), believing that idx-1 would return an array [291, ..., 578, 581 ..., 868, ... , 125281, ..., 125568]

spy(C) - m(582, 292) - (idx,idx+H+2)

spy(D) - m(292, 582) - (idx,idx-H-2)
```

What is `m(293,292)`?  Why the reverse in coordinates?  Is that because of how `spy` plots the axes?  `p(...)` for numpy code is equally confusing.  In my (smaller) samples, `A`, `B` etc all have nonzeros where I expect.

By the way, are there any zeros in `D22(idx)`?

In any case, you've created 4 sparse matrices, with values along one diagonal or other, with periodic zero gaps.

`A(idx, idx+1)` has the same nonzero values as `A`, but contiguously on the main diagonal.

Condensed version of the numpy code is:

```
In [159]: idx=np.where(mask.ravel()==1)[0]
In [160]: A=sparse.csr_matrix((np.ones_like(idx),(idx,idx+1)),shape=(N,N))
```

I'm ignoring the `F` v `C` order, and the `D22` array.  If I had `D22` matrix, I'd try to use `D22.ravel[idx]` (to match how I create and index `mask`).  I don't think those details matter when comparing the overall generation of the matrices and their indexing.

`A.tocoo().row` and `A.tocoo().col` is a handy way of seeing the row and column indexes of the nonzero elements.  `A.nonzero()` does this as well (with virtually the same code).

Yes, `A[idx,:][:,idx+1]` produces the same submatrix.

`A[idx, idx+1]` gives a 1d vector of those diagonal values.

You need to transform the first index array into a 'column' vector to select a block (as the MATLAB version does):

```
A[np.ix_(idx,idx+1)]  # or with
A[idx[:,None],idx+1]
```

Comment: Hi hpaulj, thank you for your answer. Allow me to clarify some of your questions. m(293,292) refers to the coordinates of the first entry for sparse A when I use spy(..) to plot. m(...) refers to coordinates in Matlab while p(...) is what gets returned in Python. This naming convention is just my own. I also intrigued as to why there has been a reverse in coordinates. Also, with idx+1 or idx+H+2 (+), it affects the values in x-axis, while idx-1 or idx-H-2 (-) changes values in y-axis (ORIENTATION), hence I am lead to think that perhaps Matlab sparse(i,j), where i =/= x, j =/=  y. Is that true?

Comment: I ran the code with D22 for both Matlab and Python to be matrix & array of ones respectively. In the case of Python, this is no reverse in coordinates. Thanks also for the advice on condensing of the numpy code for idx. Does it mean A=sparse.csr_matrix((-D22.ravel[idx].,(idx,idx+1)),shape=(N,N)), when D22 is not an all zeros or all ones 2D array. Finally, may I just clarify why idx+1 for A[idx,:][:.idx+1] and not A[idx,:][:.idx]? :) I truly appreciate @hpaulj all your help and comprehensive explanation and tips. Kudos to you and this community!

Comment: I have managed to solved it after proper debugging. Performing a matplotlib spy helped me to visualize the results better and they appear exactly like the matlab's one. And it is true that Matlab spy "reverses" the coordinates, so in my example m(293, 292) - 293 is the y-coords & 292 is the x-coords. Sorry for all the confusion. One more thing, would you able to help take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33410723/solve-over-determined-sparse-matrix-in-scipy-from-matlab-to-python Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Seems fine to me, the only difference I can spot is:

**MATLAB:**

```
A = sparse(idx, idx+1, -D22(idx), N, N);
B = sparse(idx, idx-1, -D22(idx), N, N);
```

**Python:**

```
A = sp.csr_matrix((-D22[idx_[:,0], idx_[:,1]], (idx+1,idx)), shape = (N,N))
B = sp.csr_matrix((-D22[idx_[:,0], idx_[:,1]], (idx,idx-1)), shape = (N,N))
```

Note that in Python for matrix B you change the index along the second dimension, whereas for matrix A you change along the first dimension.

This difference is not present in your Matlab code, whereas all other lines are "symmetric"

Comment: thanks for your reply. I realised that I made a mistake with my sample code, it should have been B = sp.csr_matrix((-D22[idx_[:,0], idx_[:,1]], (idx-1,idx)), shape = (N,N)). Hence, I posted this question.

Thanks for spotting anywway. I have edited to reflect the change, as well as additional matrices to see the difference more distinctly :)