# Solve Over-determined sparse matrix in Scipy (from Matlab to Python)

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix

Given a large sparse matrix A which are banded or tridiagonals (however it is called) and a vector f, I would like to solve for Z, where AZ = f.

There are 6 diagonals, not clearly shown here.
[image: basically there are 6 diagonals, not clearly shown here]

A has more M rows than N columns (just by 1, M ~= N), hence it is over-determined. Here is the source Matlab code, and I would like to convert it to its Scipy equivalent.

**Matlab**

```
A = A(:,2:end); #less one column
f = f(:);

Z = A\f;
Z = [0;-Z];
Z = reshape(Z,H,W);
Z = Z - min(Z(:));
```

My attempt on Scipy gives me this, but solving Z with [scipy.sparse.linalg](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html) [lsqr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.lsqr) & [lsmr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html) is a lot slower than Matlab \ as well as not giving a good enough solution. A is created as a csr_matrix.

**Python**

```
A = A[:,1:]
f = f.flatten(1)

Z = la.lsqr(A, f, atol=1e-6, btol=1e-6)
#Z = la.lsmr(A, f)   # the other method i used
Z = Z[0]
Z = np.append([0], np.negative(Z))
Z = np.reshape(Z, (height, width), order='F').copy()
Z = Z - Z.flatten(1).min()
```

Could anyone recommend a better alternative to solve for Z, that is as effective and fast as Matlab \ ?

Comment: MATLAB choses the solver for sparse matrices of A\b like this : https://uk.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2015b/matlab/ref/mldivide_sparse.png . Which solver is using for your matrix?

Comment: hi @AnderBiguri, based on the flowchart, I think it would be QR solver. Is there a way to check on Matlab?

Comment: No there is not, but it seems you are rigth.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, ok thanks. In this case, is there a scipy sparse qr?

Comment: I think that is lsqr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good candidate for [solve_banded](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_banded.html).

Unfortunately, the interface for providing the banded matrix is a little complex. You could start by converting your sparse matrix to DIA format, and work from there.